# How to remove sign up links from top menu in magento?

Tags: magento

Recently I have notcied that on my websites top menu two sign up buttons are visible. How do I remove the extra link?

Comment: By default there should be only one. I think there is something wrong in your theme. And this is kind of vague. There could be a lot of ways the "second" button is added.

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful but the two buttons are in seperate li tags. One li has class='seperator-left' and the other has a class "last"

Answer (score 0):

find following line in your theme's layout folder

```
<reference name="top.links">
```

And check there must be two instance of the link you are speaking in different files.

for ex if two Log Out links are visible, following must be inside above tag in two places.

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
```

If you have recently added any extension you must also check in its xml file.

Hope this helps

Comment: I found `<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Sign Up</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Sign Up</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>`in local.xml. Changing it didn't help

Comment: try finding it in other xml files. it must be included two times for this behaviour.

Comment: It was actually an issue with a custom theme I installed. There was an inclusion of the link in one of the cms static blocks of the theme